# does mlm loss calculate non masked token's loss too?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

In BERT, I understand what the Masked Language Model(MLM) pretraining task does, but when calculating the loss for this task, how is it exactly calculated?

It is obvious that the loss(e.g. cross entropy loss) for the masked tokens will be included in the final loss.

But what about the other tokens which aren't masked? Is loss calculated for these tokens and included in the final loss as well?

Answer (score 0):

Loss is not calculated for tokens that are not masked.